# How can I debug a missing NamespaceHandler in Aries Blueprint running in Karaf?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have debated this question over and over. It boils down to:

How can I debug Aries Blueprint running inside of Apache Karaf?

I end up with the output from `diag` which only hints at the fact that the XML namespace `http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf` cannot find a valid schema. The document schema URL is `http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-cxf-blueprint.xsd`, by the way.

```
Status: GracePeriod
Declarative Services
Blueprint
10/27/19 4:52 PM
Missing dependencies:
(&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf))
```

Yes, `camel-cxf` is running. But how can I see what exactly is going wrong?

I got as far as finding this note in the IBM documentation:

> The blueprint runtime parses the blueprint descriptors twice. The first pass is fast, and finds only every namespace that is used by the blueprint bundle. If the blueprint bundle uses a non-standard namespace, then the blueprint container attempts to locate NamespaceHandler services in the OSGi service registry for each custom namespace. A NamespaceHandler service advertises every xml namespace that it can process by using OSGi service properties. The blueprint runtime does not parse the blueprint xml until NamespaceHandler services can be found for every custom namespace that is used in the bundle. Unless NamespaceHandler services can be found for every custom namespace, the blueprint container is unable to process the bundle. This result can mean that the blueprint container waits indefinitely if no NamespaceHandler exists. If this situation is encountered, then the blueprint container issues a warning to the log. When the blueprint parser begins to parse the blueprint xml files, it parses any standard blueprint elements. When the parser reaches a custom element, the parser calls out to the NamespaceHandler that advertised support for the namespace of the custom element. Here, the NamespaceHandler has the opportunity to process the information in the custom element, modify the runtime blueprint model, or do any other operation. If there is a typing error in any of the namespace definitions, then the blueprint almost certainly fails to start.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_blueprint_namespace_handler.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my best answer, but I am hoping somebody more experienced provides a better answer.

I suspected another blueprint instance might be working against me.

I ran `list -t 0 -s | grep blueprint` in Karaf and discovered that there are two different `blueprint.api` and `blueprint.core` instances running. Is this the culprit? I do not know. I have no idea how to debug this kind of thing inside of Karaf.

```
 69 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.0.1              │ org.apache.aries.blueprint.api
 70 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.3.1              │ org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm
 71 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.10.2             │ org.apache.aries.blueprint.core
 72 │ Resolved    │  20 │ 1.0.0              │ org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility
 73 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.api
 74 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.core
 78 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.24.1             │ org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
117 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.7              │ org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate
118 │ Active      │  24 │ 4.2.7              │ org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint
120 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.7              │ org.apache.karaf.jaas.blueprint.config
```

This occurred after an upgrade of Karaf.

Other attempt to try and find out what is registering with which handlers.

```
karaf@root()> bundle:services -p org.apache.camel.camel-cxf

camel-cxf (80) provides:
------------------------
objectClass = [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler]
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace = http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf
service.bundleid = 80
service.id = 194
service.scope = bundle
----
objectClass = [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer]
osgi.blueprint.container.symbolicname = org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
osgi.blueprint.container.version = 2.24.1
service.bundleid = 80
service.id = 195
service.scope = singleton
----
objectClass = [org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.info.InfoProvider]
service.bundleid = 80
service.id = 196
service.scope = singleton
----
component = [cxf, cxfbean, cxfrs]
objectClass = [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver]
service.bundleid = 80
service.id = 197
service.scope = singleton
----
objectClass = [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader]
service.bundleid = 80
service.id = 198
service.scope = singleton
```